# Php socket write => java socket write

Tags: php, java, сокет

В пхп эта строка выглядит так:

```
  fwrite($socket, "\xFE\x01");
```

Нужно выполнить это же действие на `Java`. Не знаю, что передать вместо `something` методу `writeBytes(something)`. 
p. s.  есть `writeChars(string)`, `writeChar(char)`, если нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String charsetName="UTF8"; // или какая там кодировка на выходе вам нужна
OutputStream ous=socket.getOutputStream();

byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(charsetName);
ous.write(bytes);
```

Если вам много строк передавать, то

```
Writer ouw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ous, charsetName));
ouw.write(string, 0, string.length());
```

но только не совмещайте эти 2 способа записи - если вы передали `OutputStream ous` в конструктор `OutputStreamWriter`, то не пользуйтесь ous напрямую.

Comment: дело не в том как передать, это я умею. как передать "\xFE\x01"? Java не распознает \xFE как символ, только как строки.

Comment: ну тогда ous.write(0xFE); ous.write(0x01);

Comment: да, действительно, работает. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если это юникодовый символ то:

`String s = "\uFE01";`

Comment: это чревато тем, что при превращении юникодового символа в байты, байты могут получиться другие, в зависимости от примененной кодировки.